# How to properly install nautilus-script-collection-svn?

Tags: svn

I'me relatively new to development on linux, and i need svn.
I've installed  subversion, but command-line interface seems too creepy, so i've googled

```
nautilus-script-collection-svn
```

I've installed that too, but i cant't find it anywhere. Is that supposed to integrate into context menu? If yes, why can't i see it?

Comment: If you are just looking for svn clients, you have `rabbitvcs-nautilus`[nautilus plugin for VCS] and `rapidsvn` amongst many others

Comment: @sagarchalise i've tried rabbitvcs, rapidsvn, subversion(console), smartsvn, and finally i decided to use 'rabbitvcs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got figured that out.

> nautilus-script-manager enable Subversion

Will accept this answer ASAP